# Square API, VALUE_TOO_LOW error when charging a card

Tags: api, square-connect

I am currently working with sandbox credentials for my companies Square Up account. When I make a web service call to charge a card with an amount that is under $100, I get the following error:

```
Error calling Charge: {\"errors\":[{\"category\":\"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR\",\"code\":\"VALUE_TOO_LOW\",\"detail\":\"`amount_money.amount` must be greater than 100.\
```

I need to be able to charge for as low as $10 at a time. Is there some sort of setting in my companies account that needs to be changed in order to allow this? or is this a native Square setting that I cannot get around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The amount you are charging (if in US dollars) is in cents, not dollars. So a charge of `100` would be $1. `10` would just be ten cents. Try multiplying your value by 100. See [the documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-charge) for more details.

Comment: I am doing in AUD. is this apply same for me ?

Comment: The API charges in the lowest value of denomination for your country.